# Why is this callback function not executing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have been having this issue. It seems like it works for a while and then breaks without much rhyme or reason to it.

```
router.get('/home/', function(req, res, next) {

  var code = req.query.code;
  console.log("acquired code from SC");

  req.SC.authorize(code, function(err, accessToken) {
    if ( err ) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      console.log("traded code for access token");
      req.session.oauth_token = accessToken;
      // Client is now authorized and able to make API calls
      //res.render('home', { token: accessToken });
      soundcloud.getLoggedInUser(accessToken, function(user){
        console.log("done getting user from SC");
      });
    }
  });

});
```

Here is the getLoggedInUser function.

```
//get data for the user who is logged in
function getLoggedInUser(accessToken, done){
    var href = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/me?oauth_token=' + accessToken;
    getRequest(href, done);
}

//used for get requests to soundcloud API
function getRequest(href, done){
    console.log(href);
    requestify.get(href).then(function(response){
        console.log(done);
        done(response.getBody());
    });
}
```

Here is the output.

```
acquired code from SC
traded code for access token
https://api.soundcloud.com/me?oauth_token=
[Function]
```

I'm guessing this is a problem with my node / express setup rather than a problem with this code itself. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `requestify()`?

Comment: Also,  `if ( err ) { throw err; } ` does not do anything useful from an async callback.  You can't throw from an async callback and expect any code to be able to see that exception.  It will just be silently eaten by the async infrastructure.

Comment: FYI, your URL `https://api.soundcloud.com/me?oauth_token=1-232387-12073749-d161b3987127c3` returns a JSON response so that part appears to be working.  I'd suggest that you do a `console.log(response)` inside of `getRequest()` to see what you're getting there.  Doing `console.log(done)` is what is generating the `[Function]` output.

Comment: If it stops working after awhile, you could be hitting some API limits (too many requests perhaps).  You will have to log exactly what errors are coming back from the request to see if that gives you a clue why it stops working.  You have no error handler on `requestify()` so errors there are silent.  Anytime something stops working, make sure you log ALL error paths so you can gather info on what it going wrong.

Comment: @jfriend00 it's an http request library for node. any recommendations for a better one? i don't see any options for an error handler on this one.

Comment: It returns a promise.  Errors are reported to the second function you pass to `.then()` as in `.then(successHandler, errorHandler)`.  That's how promises work.  You aren't passing an `errorHandler`, thus you are ignoring errors.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ah, makes sense. It appears that I am not getting an error, but an empty response. I've managed to isolate the situation that the response comes blank. It occurs whenever I don't either reset my browser history/cookies or use a new incognito tab. Still not sure what the best fix would be.

Comment: @miladmaaan You should not post your working oauth_token here. People can use it to change you account